# Gauss law with charge density dependent on time

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, gauss-law

In electrostatic case, if I solve the E field using gauss law for a central point charge $Q*\delta(r)$ , I get $E_r=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}$.

In time-varying case, the gauss law is valid(proof we use it for scalar and vector potential), but when I solve the equation for central time-varying charge point $Q*e^{-i\omega t}*\delta(r)$, the solution I get is : $E_r=\frac{Q*e^{-i\omega t}}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}$.

I know the solution is wrong ,because is not include the delay/phase of the field to the change of the source(e.g. $e^{ik|r|})$.

What am I wrong?

Comment: You cannot just create charge inside the Gaussian surface as charge is a conserved quantity. You would have to move charges through the surface to increase or decrease the charge within. And as you move a charge through the surface you've moving all the field lines from that charge through the surface as well.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: MathJax is like Nike. Just do it.